# Button to auto generate text input field on click

Tags: jsp, xslt, button, jstl

I want to inset a button into my page which onclick, auto generate a body of lorem lipsum text into the text area of an imported XSL file.
I don't really want to use Javascript as I don't really like client-side scripting but rather JSTL if possible.

I was trying something like so, but no luck:

```
<button type="button" onclick="some variable?">lorem lipsum</button>
<c: if test= "onclick some variable?">
<c: import url="loremlipsum.com/xml..." var="autoGen"/>
<c: import url="my.xsl" var="stylesheet"/>
<x: transform xml="${autoGen}" xslt="${stylesheet}"/>
</c:if>
<input type="text" name="body">
```

Any thoughts on what to code for my onclick? and its variable?

Cheers

Comment: Your JSP/JSTL is creating the HTML **server-side**, but the onClick is handled **client-side**. You will likely need to specify some JavaScript that handles the onClick event.

Comment: Cheers mate, ill give it ago.